# I am trying to unboot a bootable usb

Tags: live-usb

I have made a bootable USB to dual boot Ubuntu and Kali Linux. The thing hasn't been working(different problem) so I want to try and reinstall Kali Linux. When I plug in my usb it gives the error:

```
Unable to mount Kali Live
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/peyto/Kali Live: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/peyto/Kali Live"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

In some cases useful info is found in `syslog - try dmesg | tail or so`

I looked on another page to unboot it but all it said was to do `sudo fdisk -l` When I do that it gives me 3 different USB's even though there all the same. `/dev/sdc1,2,5`.

I have an external hard drive but its memory is 100 gigs all of those were 7G,357M,357M. The next step was to:

`sudo parted /dev/sdc1 mklabel mdos`

Then I got Warning...

```
Error: Partitions 1,2,3,...,64 on /dev/sdc1 have been written, but we have 
been unable to inform the kernal of the change, probably because it/tey are in use. 
As a result, the old partitions will remain in use. You should reboot now
before making further changes.
Ignore/Cancel? Ignore
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

I know my question was long and a bit confusing but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. I can go into more detail if necessary.

Comment: If you have more details please add it.

Comment: How about reformatting the Kali partition? For an iso9660 partition it might be best to use gparted Live CD/USB, as the gparted that comes with Ubuntu does not seem to want to work with that format. (The gparted that comes with Puppy Linux also works OK for me).

Answer (score 0):

### Try the cloning method

The cloning method needs no pre-formatting, it simply overwrites the target drive with the data from the iso file (including boot sector and partition table). This works with hybrid iso files, and most current linux iso files are hybrid iso files.

I suggest that you install mkusb from the ppa according to this link

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

and use it to create a **live-only** system (using the cloning method).

If you want to use the USB drive as a regular storage device afterwards, you can use the **wipe menu** of mkusb to restore it with an MSDOS partition table and a FAT32 file system, the standard for USB pendrives.

Comment: When I use the dd command to write over everything with 0

Comment: Sorry I accidentally clicked add comment before I was done and I can't edit... Anyway it gives me the error right before I finish writing over 
"dd: error writing '/dev/sdb': No space left on device"